# $\mathbb{R}^3$ \ $\mathbb{Q}^3$ is a union of disjoint lines, The lines are not in an axis direction.

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I have a folowing question:

$\mathbb{R}^3$ \ $\mathbb{Q}^3$ is a union of disjoint lines. This exercise is in the book: Set theory for the working mathematician of Krzysztof Ciesielski.

Any can give help me in how make a selection of the disjoint lines?

Thanks.

Comment: No, that question is different

Comment: @lulu: This is not a duplicate of that question, as that one asked for the case that the lines **are** in an axis direction.

Comment: @BrandonCarter  Good point.  I'll withdraw my "duplicate" vote.